# Visual Studio - Making an application into on executable file?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

In VS, I've only tested code and debugged it, but never actually prepared anything for a finalized program or release. Some of the programs I've downloaded have had dlls that need to be in the folder they're in, and I've had programs that come as just one .exe. Is there a way to compile all the files into one application and not have external dlls? Is this bad programming practice for some reason? How do I compile my VS program into one executable file?

I know this is quite an obvious question, which is why I can't really find an answer, because it would be too obvious to write any kind of tutorial on it.

Comment: you want to create setup file for your application?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With a managed language like C# or VB.NET, [ILMerge](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=17630) is a utility that you can use.

> ILMerge is a utility for merging multiple .NET assemblies into a single .NET assembly. It works on executables and DLLs alike and comes with several options for controlling the processing and format of the output.

Answer (score 1):

If the question is just around getting VisualStudio to build executable programs, it does it every time you run them within it.  If you are using all of the default settings, open your project folder and look for a /bin directory.  Underneath it, there is a /debug and a /release directory.  If you build your program in debug mode, look in the /debug directory, if you build it in release mode, look in the release directory.  VS will put everything that your program needs within that directory.  You can copy all of those files to another machine that has the .Net runtime installed and it should run.

If the question is more about combining multiple dlls into a single exe, actually, there is a tutorial on it at CodePlex:

> As you know, traditional linking of object code is no longer necessary
>   in .NET. A .NET program will usually consist of multiple parts. A
>   typical .NET application consists of an executable assembly, a few
>   assemblies in the program directory, and a few assemblies in the
>   global assembly cache. When the program is run, the runtime combines
>   all these parts to a program. Linking at compile time is no longer
>   necessary.
>
> But sometimes, it is nevertheless useful to combine all parts a
>   program needs to execute into a single assembly. For example, you
>   might want to simplify the deployment of your application by combining
>   the program, all required libraries, and all resources, into a single
>   .exe file.

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/mergingassemblies.aspx

Lastly, if the question is about building an installer for broad distribution, Jan Willem B has a sample for WIX: [Using WIX to create an installer: quickstart tutorial](http://jwbs-blog.blogspot.com/2009/06/using-wix-to-create-installer.html)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use ILMerge for embedding managed .Net DLLs! Example [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/mergingassemblies.aspx).